# SQL minus query rows from another row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pulling information out with the code below, which works absolutely fine.

I need to pull out the data without the contractorID affecting it, then subtract the rows from the first query from it.

```
   SELECT 
 DISTINCT a.addID
        , p.propdetailID
        , p.plotID
     FROM address                AS a
LEFT JOIN propdetail             AS p   ON (a.addID = p.addID)
     JOIN housebuildertoproperty AS htp ON (htp.addID = p.addID)
     JOIN contractortopropdetail AS ctp ON (ctp.propdetailID = p.propdetailID)
    WHERE htp.housebuilderID = 1
      AND ctp.contractorID   = 1
```

So what I mean is:

1. row 1

that's the result from the first query

1. row 1
2. row 2
3. row 3

That's the result from the query without the AND ctp.contractorID = 1 part. I need code that will pull out:

1. row 2
2. row 3

I tried MINUS but phpMyAdmin just didn't accept it. I've looked into NOT IN but I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `left join` is unnecessary, because the subsequent join conditions and `where` clause turn it into an `inner join`.

Your problem is that some of the addresses on with `contractorID = 1` have other contractors.  The solution is to use `group by` instead of `distinct` and use a `having` clause to filter out addresses for contractor 1:

```
  SELECT a.addID, p.propdetailID, p.plotID
  FROM address a JOIN 
       propdetail p 
       ON (a.addID = p.addID) JOIN
       housebuildertoproperty htp
       ON (htp.addID = p.addID) JOIN
       contractortopropdetail ctp
       ON (ctp.propdetailID = p.propdetailID)
    WHERE htp.housebuilderID = 1
  GROUP BY a.addID, p.propdetailID, p.plotID
  HAVING SUM(ctp.contractorID = 1) = 0
```

Comment: That's excellent, thank you. Also kudos for explaining where I went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Please can you explain the SUM in the HAVING clause. I'm lost there.

Comment: @I.K. . . . The `sum()` in the `having` clause is counting the number of rows in each group where `contractorID = 1`.  The OP wants to exclude any group where this is the case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I thought count() function is used for counting the number of rows in each group, not sum. Please clarify.

Comment: @I.K.: SUM is for summing, yes, but since the argument (`ctp.contractorID = 1`) evaluates to either 1 or 0, SUM is effectively *counting matches* in this case.